# Trying to download multiple data from yf.download

Tags: python

I'm trying to download data from yfinance, if I use this it works:

```
data = yf.download("EURUSD=X" start="2020-01-01")
```

But if I try to add in another currency like this:

```
data = yf.download("EURUSD=X", "GBPUSD=X", start="2020-01-01")
```

I get this error:

```
data = yf.download("EURUSD=X", "GBPUSD=X", start="2020-01-01")
TypeError: download() got multiple values for argument 'start'
```

It works after adding:

```
    data = yf.download(['EURUSD=X', 'GBPUSD=X'], start="2020-01-01", group_by='ticker')
```

But I'm now trying to scan the data for candle stick patterns like morning star or engulfing bar, here's the rest of the code:

```
    engulf = talib.CDLENGULFING(data['Open'], data['High'], data['Low'], 
    data['Close'])
    morning_star = talib.CDLMORNINGSTAR(data['Open'], data['High'], 
    data['Low'], data['Close'])

    data['Morning_Star'] = morning_star
    data['Engulfing'] = engulf

    engulfing_day = data[data['Engulfing'] !=0]
    morning_star = data[data['Morning_Star'] !=0]
    print(engulfing_day)
    print(morning_star)
```

But i'm getting this error now:
return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Open'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Comment: Hey There ! Welcome to StackOverflow. Whenever you would post a question, it would be of great benefit to the folks trying to help you understand what's the expected outcome, so that they can help you better :) Cheer ! Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download the stock prices of multiple assets at once, by providing a list (such as [‘TSLA', ‘FB', ‘MSFT']) as the tickers argument.
try like this :

```
data = yf.download(['EURUSD=X','GBPUSD=X'], start="2020-01-01")
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned under the **Mass download of market data:** section of the blog posted by the Author/Maintainer of the pip package: https://aroussi.com/post/python-yahoo-finance, You need to pass tickers within a single string, though space separated:

```
>>> import yfinance as yf

>>> data = yf.download("EURUSD=X GBPUSD=X", start="2020-01-01")
[*********************100%***********************]  2 of 2 completed

>>> data.keys()
MultiIndex([('Adj Close', 'EURUSD=X'),
            ('Adj Close', 'GBPUSD=X'),
            (    'Close', 'EURUSD=X'),
            (    'Close', 'GBPUSD=X'),
            (     'High', 'EURUSD=X'),
            (     'High', 'GBPUSD=X'),
            (      'Low', 'EURUSD=X'),
            (      'Low', 'GBPUSD=X'),
            (     'Open', 'EURUSD=X'),
            (     'Open', 'GBPUSD=X'),
            (   'Volume', 'EURUSD=X'),
            (   'Volume', 'GBPUSD=X')],
           )

>>> data['Close']
            EURUSD=X  GBPUSD=X
Date
2019-12-31  1.120230  1.311303
2020-01-01  1.122083  1.326260
2020-01-02  1.122083  1.325030
2020-01-03  1.117144  1.315270
2020-01-06  1.116196  1.308010
...              ...       ...
2021-02-08  1.204877  1.373872
2021-02-09  1.205360  1.374570
2021-02-10  1.211999  1.381799
2021-02-11  1.212121  1.383260
2021-02-12  1.209482  1.382208

[294 rows x 2 columns]
```

You can also use `group_by='ticker'` in case you want to traverse over the ticker instead of the Closing price/Volume etc.

```
data = yf.download("EURUSD=X GBPUSD=X", start="2020-01-01", group_by='ticker')
```